# C++ - Aligning memory

Tags: c++, memory-alignment

I really want to understand what is happening on these two lines

```
const int PAGES = 8 * 1024;

// PAGES + extra 4KiB for alignment
uint8_t * mem = new uint8_t [ PAGES * CCPU::PAGE_SIZE + CCPU::PAGE_SIZE ];

// align to a mutiple of 4KiB
uint8_t * memAligned = (uint8_t *) (( ((uintptr_t) mem) + CCPU::PAGE_SIZE - 1) & ~(uintptr_t) ~CCPU::ADDR_MASK );
```

especially the last line, I don't understand to anything...

Comment: TL;DR: It wastes memory and you don't want any such code :)

Comment: @KubaOber: There are some limited circumstances in which page aligned memory is worth the waste; some OSes can perform optimizations to reduce memory copies when data is being read/written into/from page aligned memory. If it costs you one page of memory to get zero copy data transfers on a high load web server, that's worth it.

Comment: @ShadowRanger I'm not saying that you shouldn't align your memory, merely that you should do it by asking for page-aligned memory explicitly. After all, since `PAGES` is "large", the allocator underlying `new` will ask the OS for storage. So you might as well do that yourself, and get page-aligned storage that way. In many or even most cases, `mem` will be already aligned and then you could perhaps increment `PAGES` if it wasn't const, and avoid waste, but I don't think such hacks should be encouraged.

Comment: @KubaOber: I agree in general. Downside is that it's less portable; you'd have to write (at least) POSIX and Windows specific versions of your allocator API (using `mmap` to map anonymous memory on the former, and `VirtualAlloc` on the latter). Not impossible, and probably worth it if you're doing this a lot, but I can see why someone would try to write purely C++ standard versions of aligned allocators.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's allocating a pointer to a block of page aligned memory, that is `PAGES` number of pages using C++ allocators instead of more OS specific dedicated aligned allocation functions (e.g. [POSIX's `posix_memalign` or C11's `aligned_alloc`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/posix_memalign.3.html)).

First it allocates `PAGES + 1` pages of memory (that may or may not be page aligned), then it adjusts the resulting pointer forward so it points to the first page aligned byte in the result. By overallocating an extra page, it knows that it will definitely have a large enough allocation to have `PAGES` usable pages beyond that point. The program just needs to be sure it `delete`s `mem` when it's done, not `memAligned` (deleting the latter would probably either crash the program now, later due to heap corruption, or just leak memory; it's undefined behavior, so melting your computer to slag is a legal behavior).

That last line is numerically equivalent to rounding up to the next multiple of the page size; it adds `PAGE_SIZE - 1` to the pointer (so if the pointer was already page aligned, it's still in the same page, otherwise it's moved to the next page), then masks off the low bits of the address (which undoes the addition in the "already page aligned" case, and in all other cases, resets the pointer to the beginning of the first page following the unaligned pointer in `mem`).

The details: `~` is bitwise invert, so `ADDR_MASK`, which is probably something like `0x00000FFF` for 4096 byte pages, becomes `0xFFFFF000` (flipping all the bits). When `&`-ing a value, only bits set in both operands are kept. To give examples: For a 32 bit pointer, we'll assume `new` gave us `0xDEADBEEF`, and `PAGE_SIZE` is 4096. Adding on 4095 (`0xFFF`) means we have '0xDEADCEEE'. We then mask with `0xFFFFF000`, which eliminates the low bits, giving us `0xDEADC000`, the first page aligned address following `0xDEADBEEF`. The same thing would happen with any non-page aligned address returned by `new`.

If the value were already page aligned though, say, `0xDEADB000`, adding on 4095/`0xFFF` gets us `0xDEADBFFF` (note how no bits in `0xDEADB` changed), so when we mask to get the aligned address, we get back `0xDEADB000` again, since we were already page aligned.

The cast to `uintptr_t` is to ensure that we can manipulate the address with mathematical operators, and to ensure that bitwise invert populates all bits needed to match a pointer (if it's not sized appropriately, you might invert, then upconvert, and suddenly you'd have a bunch of zeroes on the left, not just the right, and you'd end up masking off important bits in the pointer, so it's pointing a completely different and wrong place).

Comment: Thanks, but I was rather thinking of `((uintptr_t) mem) + CCPU::PAGE_SIZE - 1) & ~(uintptr_t) ~CCPU::ADDR_MASK ` . What are these wild `~` and why do we retype to `uintptr_t` ?

Comment: @Charlestone: I was just adding that explanation. :-) Finished now, with examples.

Comment: oh, right I get it. the uintptr_t basically takes the adress and casts it like an uint32_t (64_t) right? one more thing `~(uintptr_t) ~CCPU::ADDR_MASK` - why the double negation here?

Comment: @Charlestone: Ah, missed the double negate. Most likely, `ADDR_MASK` is a (possibly 32 bit) value like `0xFFFFF000`. But if the system is 64 bit, it needs to be `0xFFFFFFFFFFFFF000`. If you just upcast it, you'd get `0x00000000FFFFF000`, which would corrupt any pointer with bits set in the upper 32 bits. By inverting to `0x00000FFF`, _then_ upcasting to add left hand `0`s, then inverting back, it's like left padding with 1 bits to match the system's notion of the size of a pointer, no matter how large a pointer is.